# Edit the subject of a forwarded message using Applescript - encountering error when editing subject line

Tags: email, applescript, osx-elcapitan

I have been trying to write some Applescript to forward a message and to edit the subject. Currently I am working on the forwarding and the populating of the recipient and the subject line.

When I run this it gives me the error:

`"Mail got an error: Can't set subject of item to any."`

Here is the code:

```
tell application "Mail"
    set theSelection to selection
    set theForwardedMessage to forward (item 1 of theSelection) with opening window
    tell theForwardedMessage
        make new to recipient with properties {address:"address@blahblah.com"}
        set subject to "blahblahblah"
    end tell
end tell
```

I can't figure out why it's telling me it can't edit the subject line. Any pointers?

Answer (score 0):

i hope this will help a little bit, but i don't fully understand your script and question.

```
set recipientName to "ZWEKKERBOY"
set recipientAddress to "john@doe.com"
set theSubject to "Subject here"
set theContent to "Content"

--Mail Tell Block
tell application "Mail"

--Create the message
set theMessage to make new outgoing message with properties {subject:theSubject, content:theContent, visible:true}

    --Set a recipient
tell theMessage
        make new to recipient with properties {name:recipientName, address:recipientAddress}

    --Send the Message
    send

end tell
end tell
```

-- credit to maker!

You can change the

```
set theSubject to "Subject here"
```

line

to

```
set theSubject to subject
-- that's "blahblahblah"
```